# filled has private access in GeometricObject

Tags: java

[image]
[image]

I have an error on this and I don't understand. Can someone please explain to me why I get this error and how would I fix it?

Comment: Please add the code here instead of images. So that we can try to help you

Comment: what are you trying to do? why are you trying to call `super` with a field that belongs to the superclass? Where do you think the value is coming from?

Comment: As looking into image, private member cannot access outside class directly, Please provide code instead of image so it will be more clear.

Comment: Even if you shouldn't have code as images, you should at least have the images inline.

Comment: @RasmusW New members cannot post inline images, exactly because you shouldn't be posting images unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use private fields of supercalass in subclass. Try change *private* on *protected*. And look at [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java-4th/9781449372477/ch06s04.html).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to use private field from parent class in inherited class. You can make field `protected` or `public` in `GeometricObject` class. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is explained access modifiers in java.

```
public class GeometricObject
{
     protected String color;
     protected boolean filled;
}
```